# libtensorflow_core.a missing symbols (tensorflow::port::InitMain(char const*, int*, char***)

Tags: c++, tensorflow, makefile

I have compiled the static library libtensorflow_core.a in the tensorflow/contrib/makefiles/gen/lib folder using the

```
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_linux.sh
```

script

Making some minor adjustments for CentOS 6.10 to include a LD_LIBRARY_PATH for libstdc++ as the gcc that comes with CentOS 6 is gcc 4.4 and gcc 4.8 is needed for C++11

I have tested the compile was successful by testing the benchmark binary with my model

```
./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/bin/benchmark etc
```

This all works as expected.

Now I am hosting Tensorflow in my application, which was previously dynamically linked to libtensorflow_cc.so and libtensorflow_framework.so

instead I am linking to libtensorflow_core.a statically

Compiling and linking of my plugin are successful.

```
At runtime the following error occurs:
/usr/local/Nuke11.3v1/Nuke11.3: symbol lookup error: /usr/OFX/Plugins/rotobot.ofx.bundle/Contents/Linux-x86-64/rotobot.ofx: undefined symbol: _ZN10tensorflow4port8InitMainEPKcPiPPPc
```

We can see the symbol missing is

```
tensorflow::port::InitMain(char const*, int*, char***)
```

my code indeed contains this function

```
[samh@apollo-centos6 Rotobot-CPU-static]$ grep -rn InitMain rotobot.cpp
130:    tensorflow::port::InitMain(&usage[0], &argc, NULL);
```

What adjustments do I need to make to my the libtensorflow_core.a Makefile to include InitMain?

Sam

I can see that this function is in the benchmark binary which works

and I can also see that the benchmark source are as follows

```
BENCHMARK_SRCS := \
tensorflow/core/util/reporter.cc \
tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model.cc \
tensorflow/tools/benchmark/benchmark_model_main.cc
```

the LIBS flags for my compile are the libprotobuf.a and libtensorflow_core.a and the other things needed for my application

I think if you had the following

```
#include <tensorflow/core/platform/init_main.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
   char usage[] = "iLikeTurtles";
    tensorflow::port::InitMain(&usage[0], &argc, NULL);
}
```

it would be enough to trigger the error

I would expect the program to function the same as the code linked against libtensorflow_cc.so and libtensorflow_framework.so

looking into

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/benchmark/BUILD

```
    deps = select({
        "//tensorflow:android": [
            "//tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib",
            "//tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_test_lib",
        ],
        "//conditions:default": [
            "//tensorflow/core:core_cpu",
            "//tensorflow/core:lib",
            "//tensorflow/core:framework",
            "//tensorflow/core:framework_internal",
            "//tensorflow/core:framework_lite",
            "//tensorflow/core:protos_all_cc",
            "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
            "//tensorflow/core:test",
        ],
    }),
```

Looks like we might need the .o files for framework, framework_internal, and framework_lite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the devil is in the detail

here are the library args to use the static library

```
-Wall -L$(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf-host/lib -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive  $(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/libtensorflow-core.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive $(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/builds/default.linux.c++11/nsync.a -lstdc++ -l:libprotobuf.a -lz -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt
```

Then everything works great

This was deciphered by looking at make VERBOSE=true when executing the build_all_linux.sh

and looking at the last command for building and linking the benchmark executable

you may not need -lrt but I do on CentOS 6.10

I still need to do the same on OSX

Building on OSX is still using the build_all_linux.sh script as OSX is close enough to Linux

```
    TENSORFLOW_LIBS = -Wl,-force_load,$(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/libtensorflow-core.a -Wl,-force_load,$(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/builds/default.macos.c++11/nsync.a  -Wl,-force_load,$(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf-host/lib/libprotobuf.a -lstdc++ -lz -lpthread
```

Comment: Building on OSX is still using the build_all_linux.sh script as OSX is close enough to Linux

     TENSORFLOW_LIBS = -Wl,-force_load,$(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/libtensorflow-core.a -Wl,-force_load,$(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/nsync/builds/default.macos.c++11/nsync.a  -Wl,-force_load,$(TENSORFLOW)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/protobuf-host/lib/libprotobuf.a -lstdc++ -lz -lpthread